# why does this php code return me 13 and not 3? I'm really confused

Tags: php, for-loop, echo, modulo

Can someone tell me why the output of `echo` of this Code is 13?

```
$a=10;
$b=2;
$j=$a/2;
for ($i=0;$i<$j;$i++){
    if ($i % $b == 1) 
    echo "$i";
}
```

Comment: I think it is more like a 1 and a 3 rather than 13

Comment: `echo 1; echo 3;` output `13`

Comment: What you want to do ? with this code ?

Comment: Print everything in a new line. Also, this is kinda like a typo. Soon will get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a=10;
$b=2;
$j=$a/2;  //which will be 5
for ($i=0;$i<$j;$i++){ //the loop executes 5 times 
    if ($i % $b == 1) // this condition satisfies when $i becomes 1 && 3
    echo "$i"; //1 and 3 will be printed.
}
```

Check The comments written in your code

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?php
    $a=10;
    $b=2;
    $j=$a/2;
    echo $j;
    echo "<br>";
    for ($i=0;$i<$j;$i++){
        if ($i % $b == 1) 
        echo "$i";
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

- because $a have 10 value , $b have 2 value and $j have 5 value

when start loop then $i start from 0 loop have max 5 loops from 0 to 4
so

1. then loop start first then *$i have 0* value so **$i % will be equal
   1** so nothing display
2. when start second loop then *$i have 1* value then **$i % will be
   equal 1** so **display 1 because now $i have 1 value**
3. when loop run third time then *$i have 2* value then **$i % will be
   equal 0** so nothing display
4. when loop run fourth time then *$i have 3* value then **$i % will be
   equal 1** **so display 3 because now $i have 3 value**
5. when loop run fifth time then **$i have 4** value then **$i % will
   be equal 0** so nothing display

Answer (score 0):

You code is like this,

```
echo 1; echo 3;
```

output 13

Answer (score 0):

I hope that will help you understand how your code works.

```
$a=10;
$b=2;
$j=$a/2;
for ($i=0;$i<$j;$i++){
    if ($i % $b == 1)
    echo "output"; 
    echo "$i";
}
```

Comment: `will help you understand` without comment and description ?

Comment: Just added output string so that he knows 1 and 3 are separate outputs.